# How to get more than one speech results in sphinx 4 using SpeechResult api?

Tags: speech-recognition, speech, cmusphinx, sphinx4, jsapi

`result.getHypothesis()` doesn't always give me best result so I want multiple results after recognization. I tried the code below, it returns me an empty array. Recognizer is an object of LiveSpeechRecognizer.

```
SpeechResult result = recognizer.getResult();
System.out.println( result.getNbest(10));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use grammars, n-best is not supported yet. If you use language models you should see n-best results as in Transcriber demo.